# How would I grab everything before the first ' . ' and use it as a variable?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gzip, one-liner

I have a ton of .gz files, all zeek and zipped.

Just a few.

```
broker.17:22:58-17:45:10.log.gz
broker.18:22:58-18:30:20.log.gz
weird.17:22:58-17:45:10.log.gz
weird.18:22:58-18:30:20.log.gz
```

My end goal is to combine all of the log.gz per each zeek type into one file containing the information of all of the files per that type.
The issue is that I have multiple directories as a day, within each all zeek types in .gz with 1 zip per hour.

I have tried :

```
for f in *.gz ; do grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)' 'print {$f}' ; done
```

*Edits: I was trying to use one liners just to test this:
ERROR: grep:  '.*?(?=.)' no such file or directory.

My goal here was to test that I can grab the first of each, example: broker, weird, conn.

After that I would take the variable and do something of the sort of:

```
cat broker*.gz >> /home/user/new/path/to/single/combined/file.gz
gunzip -c ~/combined/file.gz > /final/unzipped/pathto/file.log
```

basically I have a ton of old zeek logs on security onion sensors and I want to get them sent to splunk.
if you know the security onion file structure it follows: /nsm/zeek/logs/[date]/[gzip of every zeek type for every hour].log.gz

Comment: Your shell statement is messed up. If you tried something that actually ran, please copy and paste that, _exactly_ into the question. Don't type random crap into your question. There is no `do` to go with the `done`. There is an unbalanced single quote. Looks like there is a missing semicolon and an `awk`. We can't help you if you don't show us what you _actually_ tried.

Comment: You also need to include what shell you're using. sh? bash? zsh? Something else? And add that to your tags.

Comment: If you are using BASH, you might investigate bash parameter expansion.  Something like `for fname in *.gz ; do echo "${fname%%.*}" ; done`

Comment: @j_b Thank you, I was able to do this as one liners: ```for fname in *.gz ; do cat "${fname%%.*}"*.gz >> /home/orafreaz/target/"${fname%%.*}".log.gz ; done``` then cd to ```target``` and do  ```for file in *.gz ; do gunzip -c "$file" > /home/orafreaz/unzipped/"${file%.*}" ; done``` Now what I need to learn is how to make this as a script and do it for all of the directories within /nsm/zeek/logs/[date] It looks like this ```2022-08-31 2022-09-01```     
```2022-09-02 2022-09-02```